# ModuleNotFoundError on venv after upgrade to Ubunbtu 20.04

Tags: python-venv, ubuntu-20.04

I've just upgraded my home server OS to Ubuntu 20.04 and having funny problems.
It seems like somehow python's PATH information is messed up.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myname/dirname/venvname/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

After brief research, I've figured out Ubuntu 20.04 dropped support on Python2.
So I installed Python2 and pip manually and tried the above command again, but still throwing the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myname/dirname/venvname/bin/gunicorn", line 6, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn'
```

Moreover, It throws the same kind of error for Gunicorn.
So, I believe this is not a problem just related to Python2.

I know it is insufficient information for diagnostic, but I have no idea what would be helpful.
So any guess or ask for additional information would be appreciated.

EDIT 1) I've reinstall python on venv with

```
sudo apt purge python3
sudo apt install python3
```

and still have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I realise I will have to do a clean install of 20.04 in this case.

Comment: Have you tried installing pip? `sudo apt install python3-pip`

Answer (score 0):

Does `python3 -m pip` works? I am not sure if it would work, but I resolved this kind of error by invoking `pip` like this previously.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted you because this is not an answer but a question :-) It would be better suited to post as a comment.

Comment: I could not comment to the question because I didn't have enough reputation to comment. I just wanted to help.

Comment: Please don't let my downvote disappoint you! I really appreciate you trying to help, and I didn't realize you needed reputation to comment.

Now back on topic, I think the original problem is that the `pip` module is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

After some tries, I've give up the original venv and make a new one. There was some chore to setup venv and project again, but it works just fine.

If anyone has the same issue, consider re-make another venv.